# Installing XMR-stak CPU only on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: cpu-mining, ubuntu, installation, xmr-stak

Where can I find instructions for installing XMR-stak CPU on Ubuntu 18.04.  I notice every one are having issues with their graphic cards, however I just want to use my CPU. That being said I am still having issues installing and or loading the program on Ubuntu.

Comment: Couldn't you just use the --noNVIDIA --noAMD flags?

Answer (score 1):

You can find instructions on xmr-stak repository itself.
You should basically download the ubuntu/debian release, extract the file, and launch the miner through cli.
It does auto configuration on the first launch IIRC.

Answer (score 1):

If using the flags to disable the GPUs doesn't work.  You can compile it for only CPU: (probably need to be root or sudo it)

```
apt install libmicrohttpd-dev libssl-dev cmake build-essential libhwloc-dev
git clone https://github.com/fireice-uk/xmr-stak.git
mkdir xmr-stak/build
cd xmr-stak/build
cmake .. -DCUDA_ENABLE=OFF  -DOpenCL_ENABLE=OFF
make install
```

Comment: Only the first line need root/sudo. If all dependencies are present, neither compiling nor running xmr-stak requires root.

Comment: You do not need to compile yourself not to use graphics cards. There are config and runtime settings to disable mining on gfx cards and even without these settings/flags used, xmr-stak simply wont create gpu configs for cards it can't mine with anyway. It may show errors, but then proceed to mine just using CPU.

Comment: @Dave you are god in my high red eyes

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, if you want to use CPU only, take a look at [XMRig](https://github.com/xmrig/xmrig). It's only for CPU and works great.

It's also easy to install.